# "Copy" does not create independent copy of Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, delphi

With reference to on-line documentation found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays.

It is quite clearly written that to make an independent copy of a dynamic array, use the Copy() function. Example code found at that link also illustrates that after the copy, if you change one array, it is not reflected into the other array as both are independent copies. It does not work for me, however. After the copy as well, if I change one array, the other array automatically changes to receive the same value thus implying that Copy() just did what X := Y would have done. Per documentation, "X := Y" and "X := Copy(Y)" are *NOT* same.

Here is my code:

```
type
  TTestArray = array of TMyType; //Note: TMyType is a class and not a record.

var
  X, Y, Z: TTestArray;

begin
  SetLength(X, 1); //create first array
  X[0].testString := 'Test Y';
  Y := copy(X);
  X[0].testString := 'Test Z'; //re-assign another value
  Z := copy(X);
  X[0].testString := 'Test X';
```

at this time, testString field should contain different text. So,

```
X[0].testString should be 'Test X'
Y[0].testString should be 'Test Y'
Z[0].testString should be 'Test Z'
```

However, all three just have 'Test X' as the value in testString thus implying that Copy() did not create independent copies of the array X. Rather, all three arrays are pointing to the same memory location.

Any way to reliably create independent copies of dynamic arrays (i.e. accomplish what I am trying to do above)?

**NOTE (added later):** TMyType is a class and not a record. So, per very helpful comments below, this is an expected behavior in case of a CLASS. So, how would I make independent copy of the X into Y and Z in this case?

**NOTE 2:** Removed "Bug" from subject line. Sorry, Embarcadero...

**Note 3:** TMyType has to be a class. I have no control over it. It is being created from a web service definition (WSDL) which exposes some functionality of PeopleSoft.

Comment: Add the definition of TMyType, if it is a class, then the behavior you complain about is obviously correct. If it's a record then something is amiss.

Comment: If TMyType is an object then you are just copying a reference to the object so all 3 arrays will contain the same object.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a new XE6 console app, added a definition for `TMyType`=`record testString: string; end;`, and added three WriteLns to display the content, along with a ReadLn and the missing `end.`, and ran it. I received exactly the output you'd expect (and that your second clodeblock shows). What is your definition of `TMyType`?

Comment: very good point. TMyType is actually a CLASS. So, per comments here, it is the expected behavior. Hmmm.... OK, so how do I make an independent copy of the dynamic array in this case. Due to dynamic nature of the run-time, if I try to create a new variable every time, I would have to declare how knows how many up front and then keep track of which ones have been used blah blah blah. Very inefficient and not elegant at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Not everything that you don't understand is automatically a bug. Actually, although there are indeed compiler and RTL bugs, it is very unlikely you hit one. It is much more likely the bug is in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `TMyType` as:

```
type
  TMyType = class(SomeObject)
  ....
  public
    testString: string;
  end;
```

When you create the initial `TestArray`, it **does not** get filled with the objects itself, but only with pointers to these objects.

**What's going on...**
The array thus looks like this:

```
Array           contents of array     contents of the heap
-------------+----------------------+-----------------------
X[0]         |-> pointer_to_MyType1 |-> MyType1
X[1]         |-> pointer_to_MyType2 |-> MyType2
```

When you copy the array this is what happens:

```
Array           contents of array            contents of the heap
-------------+------------------------------+-----------------------
Y[0]         |-> copy_of_pointer_to_MyType1 |-> MyType1
Y[1]         |-> copy_of_pointer_to_MyType2 |-> MyType2
```

**What you would like to see...**
This is what you expected to happen:

```
Array           contents of array            
-------------+-------------------
X[0] or Y[0] |-> (copy of)MyType1
X[0] or Y[0] |-> (copy of)MyType2
```

**How to make that happen**
However in order for that to be possible you have to define `TMyType` as:

```
type
  TMyType = record
  public
    TestString: string;
  end;
```

Now the record itself will be stored in the array and not a pointer to data stored elsewhere.

> **how would I make independent copy of the X into Y and Z in this case?**

If you want to retain the use of classes then you'd have to write your own version of `Copy`; something like:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, system.classes, Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyList<T: TPersistent, constructor > = class(TList<T>)
  public
    function CloneArray: TMyList<T>;
  end;

implementation

function TMyList<T>.CloneArray: TMyList<T>;
var
  i: integer;
  temp: T;
begin
  Result:= TMyList<T>.Create;
  for i:= 0 to SizeOf(self) -1 do begin
    temp:= T.Create;
    temp.assign(self.items[i]);
    Result.Add(temp);
  end; {for i}
end;
```

Obviously the above code assumes that you can get away with using a parameterless constructor.

See also: [Correct way to duplicate Delphi object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041760/correct-way-to-duplicate-delphi-object)

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful reply and the time you took to explain it so well. However, unfortunately, I have no control over TMyType. It is being created from a WSDL, and Delphi created it as a CLASS. I don't want to go into the auto-generated web-service interface file in Delphi and start modifying it because that will be opening a can of worms... :( So, anyway to create an independent copy of the dynamic array in this case without having to declare separate variables in each and every case?

Comment: Johan, I am accepting your answer as it answered my original question. Thanks much. I have opened another question where the objective remains and I have added actuals definitions of all classes. If you could kindly visit that one too, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447183/delphi-making-independent-copies-of-dynamic-arrays-of-classes

Answer (score 3):

You should rather create a new question instead of changing or adding to your question/

To answer the second part of your question, the easiest thing would be to create you own CopyMyTypeArray function. Your code for the this would probably be something like this:

```
function CopyMyTypeArray(ASource: TTestArray): TTestArray;
var
  newObject: TMyType;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(ASource));
  for cntr := Low(ASource) to High(ASource) do
  begin
    // You could put the lines below into a clone method
    newObject := TMyType.Create;
    newObject.testString := ASource[cntr].testString;
    Result[cntr] := newObject;
  end;
end;
```

Please note that you would need to free the objects if you free the dynamic array.

If you are happy with this solution please accept Johan's solution as that answers your initial question.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted Johan's answer and opened a new question with actually class definitions, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447183/delphi-making-independent-copies-of-dynamic-arrays-of-classes

Answer (score 1):

If you need independent copies of objects, the easiest way is to write a Copy Constructor. A copy constructer takes one argument - a reference to the existing object to be copied - and then initializes its internal fields to the same values as in the original object. This can be done with simple code, or using RTTI.

See also: [Correct way to duplicate Delphi object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041760/correct-way-to-duplicate-delphi-object)

A configurable TMyTypeFactory (or TMyTypeBuilder) might be also an alternative solution.

Comment: This could be done with a class helper but probably not on the original object as it's imported so there is a good chance that the OP can't change the object.

Comment: That's correct. I can't change the object. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447183/delphi-making-independent-copies-of-dynamic-arrays-of-classes. THANKS!