# How to handle a plain dynamic array using generics?

Tags: delphi, generics

I know how to manipulate the derived generic classes like TList etc.

However when I want to manipulate a plain dynamic array I run into difficulties.

How do I translate the following code into a version that uses generics?

```
//code A
function CloneArray(original: TArray_Of_TX): TArray_Of_TX;
var
  i: integer;
  copy: TX;
begin
  Result.SetLength(SizeOf(original));
  for i:= 0 to SizeOf(original) -1 do begin
    copy:= TX.Create;
    copy.assign(original[i]);
    Result[i]:= copy;
  end; {for i}
end;
```

**If** I was using a TList, the generic version would be:

```
//code B (works, but not on a plain dynamic array)
uses
  System.SysUtils, system.classes, Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyList<T: TPersistent, constructor > = class(TList<T>)
  public
    function CloneArray: TMyList<T>;
  end;

implementation

function TMyList<T>.CloneArray: TMyList<T>;
var
  i: integer;
  temp: T;
begin
  Result:= TMyList<T>.Create;
  for i:= 0 to SizeOf(self) -1 do begin
    temp:= T.Create;
    temp.assign(self.items[i]);
    Result.Add(temp);
  end; {for i}
end;
```

However that code does not work for `TArray<T>`, because you cannot access its `Items` property, it has none. If you use the `array of ...` I don't see how you can use generics.

**How do I write a general/generics version of code A above?**

*See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446648/650492
And my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23447527/650492*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
type
  TArray = class
    class function Clone<T: TPersistent, constructor>(const original: array of T): TArray<T>; static;
  end;

function TArray.Clone<T>(const original: array of T): TArray<T>;
var
  i: integer;
  copy: T;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(original));
  for i := 0 to Length(original) - 1 do 
  begin
    copy := T.Create;
    copy.Assign(original[i]);
    Result[i] := copy;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Could an open array be used here? I would also comment that this approach is probably not very useful in practise because it demands that the class has a parameterless constructor. A great many classes don't, or need to be constructed using a different constructor.

Comment: What would be the other choice? Either having a callback getting passed in that does the cloning or have a constraint on some base class that implements a Clone method or implement some interface that has such method. Anyway this was not the subject of the question but to implement the given routine in a generic way.

Comment: The thing is that the parameterized constructor is superfluous here, because the assign already copies all member data. Should we then perhaps use tpersistent.create for the object and bypass the parameterized create of the actual object. I'm not even sure that's possible.

Comment: @Johan Assign is not a substitute for running a constructor. Plenty of classes need particular constructors to run. If your intended use case does not then that is fine, but the code here is only generic up to a point. Generics really are not cut out for object instantiation.